# Can't install android SDK on windows 7 - 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, android-studio, sdk

I have installed `AndroidStudio` on my windows 7 OS. I tried to install `SDK-Tools` using android web-site and the `Android SDK` section in `Settings` looked like this:

[image]

There is nothing enable to select except the `Edit` link. I clicked on it and another window was raised:

[image]

I have specified an existing path on my system (as you can see in the image), but I couldn't check the package to be installed. When I clicked on `Next` in this state, I got this:

[image]

What is wrong with my installation? Do I have to install something else prior to this? Why is it said `(installed)` in front of `Android SDK` in the second image?